# How can I get the entire updated entry in a $afterUpdate hook in objection models?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, objection.js

Im using Objection.js as my ORM for a simple rainfall application. I need to be able to dynamically update and entry of one table when a lower level tables entires has been updated. To do this I need the whole entry I am updating so I can use that data to correctly update the dynamically updated entry.

Im using the `$afterUpdate` hook for  the lower level table entry which. The issue I am having is that when I log `this` within the `$afterUpdate` hook function it only contains the properties for the parts of the entry I want to update. How can I get the entire entry? Im sure I could get the record by running an additional query to the DB but I was hoping there would be away to avoid this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, as of right now, you can only get the whole model with an extra query. 
If you are doing the update with an instance query ($query) you can get the other properties from `options.old`.

Query:

```
const user = await User.query().findById(userId);
await user.$query()
          .patch({ name: 'Tom Jane' })
```

Hook:

```
$afterUpdate(opt, queryContext) {
  console.log(opt.old)
}
```

---

**Patch**

If you don't need to do this in the hook, you might want to use `patch` function chained with `first().returning('*')` to get the whole model in a single query, it's more efficient than `patchAndFetchById` in postgreSQL. Like stated in the documentation.

> Because PostgreSQL (and some others) support returning('*') chaining, you can actually insert a row, or update / patch / delete (an) existing row(s), and receive the affected row(s) as Model instances in a single query, thus improving efficiency. See the examples for more clarity.

```
const jennifer = await Person
  .query()
  .patch({firstName: 'Jenn', lastName: 'Lawrence'})
  .where('id', 1234)
  .returning('*')
  .first();
```

References:

- http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#postgresql-quot-returning-quot-tricks
- https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/185
- https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/695

Comment: Thanks this worked. Using the returning() method worked for me.